# Decode XML Spreadsheet content of a clipBoard generated by Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, clipboard, spreadsheetml

I want to do a very simple thing in my program :

When a user do a copy of a selection in Excel (2007 - 2016), I want to be able to read the clipboard content, then extract all the values.

Currently Excel puts into the clipboard lots a different formats like Biff5, Biff8, CSV, plain/text etc.

One simple solution could be to use the CSV format but that's not precise enough because if I tumble on a number, I wouldn't know if it was a String or a number in the excel file. Also the dates are sent in their original format and it will be a pain to understand it.

So the solution I see is to parse the "XML Spreadsheet" sent by Excel which looks like that :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Feuil1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3"
   ss:DefaultColumnWidth="60" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">8</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">9</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R[-2]C:R[-1]C)"><Data ss:Type="Number">17</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Before you ask, I've considered POI. But as far as I understood I need to use XSSF. But to use that I need poi-ooxml, and to use that I need poi-ooxml-schemas and poi. I don't know the total weight of these JARs but I'm not keen on the fact to add 10Mb of jars just to extract an information from a clipBoard.

Has anyone ever tried to do that? Is there a project that could do that?

Comment: If you just want simple cell values, you could knock up a custom SAX parser in a couple of hundred lines of code, using the built-in JVM XML processing stuff

Comment: This XML-format does not look like the same as the one in the docx-files, so you will need to parse this differently in any case and POI would not be able to parse it even with all the libs.

Comment: I implemented a custom parser and did it myself.. Quite off nobody did that before.. I'll put that in my github and upload the link here in case anyone wants to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code to resolve the issue can be found here :

https://github.com/Maxoudela/XMLSpreadsheetParser

Comment: Thanks, I don't suppose you have a good solution for actually putting formatted excel data on to the clipboard do you?

Comment: In order to put some Excel data in the clipBoard, you can either use Apache POI but it's kind of complicated. I usually put some HTML in the clipboard and Excel understand it. You can put some tr and td tag . I can put an example on GitHub if you are interested.

Comment: That's how I've done it at the minute (with HTML) but I can't get the column widths to be detected and it's annoying ,but it it ends up begin way more complicated then probably not worth the bother, thank you.